# Password protecting the Tor browser

Tags: security

I'd like to password protect the Tor browser on my computer so that others cannot open it without a password. Is there a simple way of doing so? I am on a Mac using OSX. So far, I'm thinking the best solution might be to move Tor to a password protected folder?

Comment: uh, surely other users would need to be logged into your account to do so, and if you have multiple accounts they shouldn't share anything you've done to change Tor Browser (e.g. adding bookmarks, etc) since they're stored under the users `$HOME` directory? So you could just password protect your account?

Comment: Ah! Well I guess I don't use good info hygiene/security in my office. All staff log in the same. Short of creating separate logins for everyone using the computers -- which would be pretty inconvenient -- is there a way to just cordone off the Tor app?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with macOS, but you might get better replies in a more macOS specific forum? Since it should really apply generically to any macOS app, right? So it may be worth your while asking there too, if no one here can give you a good answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either use [mac app locker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/applocker-password-lock-apps/id1132845904?mt=12) or a custom applications for this task, like [this one](https://www.cisdem.com/resource/password-protect-applications-on-mac.html)